# SVN: how to set external property on a remote repository through command line

Tags: batch-file, svn

I'm trying to create a batch that can automatize the set of an external property on a remote tag. This batch should run on windows.

I usually accomplish this operation through Tortoise SVN Repo Browser as showed in the image below:

[image: Edit of external property]
I've tryed to use this command line to do the same operation

```
svn propset svn:externals 'LocalPath https://svnserver/svn/myproject/tags/1.00/DISTRIBUZIONE89' https://svnserver/svn/myproject/tags/Distribuzione
```

but it seems to not work on a remote repository.

Is it possible run a command line, executable in a batch, that performs this operation?

Many thanks...

Comment: I would use [procmon](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx) to catch the exact command line used by TortoiseSVN's GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

svn propset does not operate with URLs, it require checked out working copy. So script should look like(not checked):

```
svn co --depth empty https://svnserver/svn/myproject/tags/Distribuzione wc
svn propset svn:externals "LocalPath https://svnserver/svn/myproject/tags/1.00/DISTRIBUZIONE89" wc
svn ci -m "Set externals"
```

P.S. I guess TortoiseSVN use same trick with temp checkout, or use some Subversion API not exposed via command line.

Comment: Hey how to update existing svn:externals property and also it is multi line using command prompt

Answer (score 0):

Use bat file windows :-

```
svn checkout {tag url where property is to be set} {tempfoldername} --depth empty
echo {target value url for property} {foldername} > {tempfilename}
svn propset svn:externals tempfoldername -F tempfilename
svn commit -m "your commit message" tempfoldername
RD /S /Q tempfoldername
del /F /Q tempfilename
```